# Auto Timestamping a cell when certain cells have been editted

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I am trying to make it so if any cells between `I4:AI503` on the spreadsheet listed below gets edited, it will update the timestamp in column `AK`.

The following code is used in this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y0KvuZu2kTg-c2AYtmhxXp2t_wNR8Hh5RetWjJ5Y6Gs/edit?usp=sharing):

```javscript
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (ss.getName() == "RS3 Points") {
    var range = ss.getActiveCell();
    var col = range.getColumn();
    var row = range.getRow();
    if ((col >= 9) && (col <= 35) && (row > 3)) {
      var ActiveCell = ss.getRange().getRow()
      var TimestampCol = ss.getLastColumn()
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy");
      var GetRange = ss.getRangeByName(ActiveCell, TimestampCol)
      GetRange.setValue(formattedDate)
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure column AK is formatted as Date. Then, try this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== "RS3 Points" || 
    e.range.columnStart < 9 || e.range.columnStart > 35 || 
    e.range.rowStart < 4 || e.range
    .columnStart < e.range.columnEnd) return;
e.range.offset(0, 37 - e.range.columnStart).setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: That does the job, but the only thing is the numbers get cleared at the end of every month, so when i highlight the area and delete everything whether the box has anything in or not it will update it

Comment: and you want it the timestamp gone if there is nothing in that row ?

Comment: i want the row to serve as a record of when they were active, i will be adding conditional formatting later on to change the colour of the box if it goes over 62 days

Comment: also if i delete multiple columns it adds multiple columns with todays date

Comment: the problem with that is i cannot track activity cause as soon as i clear the points at the end of the month it will remove the date out of their last active, is there anyway to recognise an input only and not a deletion?

Comment: I think the first version was like that. Ok. updated again so that the stamp only appears on input (not deletion). Can you check ?

Comment: not sure if you updated the code its still removing timestamp upon deletion

Comment: Sorry... was on the phone and forgot all about it.. :-)

Comment: tried to copy and paste the code to work on two different sheets but the code that worked on the first sheet stopped working - UvdXqWWb

Comment: If you want the script to work on other sheet, you can't simply copy the first one. You can't have more than one onEdit. So instead you'll have to change the code so that it also works for the other sheet. As far as the current script concerns, I think it answered your question..If you need more help, at least upvote or accept the answer..

Comment: ok.. now on what sheets do you want the script to run ? Are the ranges the same ?

Comment: heres the pastebin /UvdXqWWb